# DB2 trigger new view doesn't reflect data updated by previous triggers

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

Let's say I have created the following tables:

```sql
create table SAMPLE (
    ID INTEGER,
    COL_A INTEGER,
    COL_B INTEGER
);
create table SAMPLE_CLONE (
    ID INTEGER,
    COL_A INTEGER,
    COL_B INTEGER
);
```

And I have created the following triggers:

```sql
-- Increment COL_A on every update
CREATE TRIGGER INC_COL_A AFTER UPDATE ON SAMPLE
REFERENCING  OLD AS oldrow  NEW AS newrow  
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL 
WHEN (oldrow.COL_A = newrow.COL_A)
UPDATE SAMPLE SET COL_A = COL_A+1 WHERE ID = oldrow.ID;

-- Replicate inserts from SAMPLE to SAMPLE_CLONE
CREATE TRIGGER REPLICATE_INSERTED_DATA
AFTER INSERT ON SAMPLE
REFERENCING NEW AS newrow
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
INSERT INTO SAMPLE_CLONE (ID, COL_A, COL_B) VALUES (newrow.ID, newrow.COL_A, newrow.COL_B);

-- Replicate updates from SAMPLE to SAMPLE_CLONE
CREATE TRIGGER REPLICATE_UPDATED_DATA
AFTER UPDATE ON SAMPLE
REFERENCING NEW AS newrow OLD AS oldrow
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
UPDATE SAMPLE_CLONE SET COL_A = newrow.COL_A, COL_B = newrow.COL_B WHERE ID = newrow.ID;
```

The issue I'm having is that, after I run any update on SAMPLE table, the COL_A latest value incremented by trigger `INC_COL_A`, is not reflected into the `newrow` during the trigger REPLICATE_UPDATED_DATA processing. For example, if I have the following data:

```sql
INSERT INTO SAMPLE (ID, COL_A, COL_B) VALUES (1, 1, 100);
```

SAMPLE

| ID | COL_A | COL_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |

SAMPLE_CLONE

| ID | COL_A | COL_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |

Then, after running the following command:

```sql
UPDATE SAMPLE SET COL_B = 200 WHERE ID = 1;
```

I get the following results committed on these tables:

SAMPLE

| ID | COL_A | COL_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 200 |

SAMPLE_CLONE

| ID | COL_A | COL_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 200 |

Notice that the record on `SAMPLE_CLONE.COL_A` wasn't replicated by the `REPLICATE_UPDATED_DATA` trigger because it didn't get the update made by `INC_COL_A` trigger.

I'm having this issue with DB2 11.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers that share event, time and target are executed in the order they were created. Each `BEFORE` trigger can modify `NEW ROW`, subsequent `BEFORE` triggers will use that modified row. Each `AFTER` trigger will all receive the same final row, none of them can modify it.

Here `INC_COL_A` and `REPLICATE_UPDATED_DATA` are executed in this order.

So when `UPDATE SAMPLE SET COL_B = 200 WHERE ID = 1;` is run

1. DB2 produces an intermediate row with `COLB_B = 200`
2. `INC_COL_A` is triggered, executes `UPDATE SAMPLE SET COL_A = 2`
3. This update triggers `INC_COL_A` again but since `COL_A` is the same in old and new row nothing happens
4. `REPLICATE_UPDATED_DATA` handles the row with `COL_A = 2, COL_B = 200` and replicates it into `SAMPLE_CLONE`
5. The UPDATE statement inside `INC_COL_A` is now done, but `REPLICATE_UPDATED_DATA` still has to handle `COL_A = 1, COL_B = 200`.

In the end, `COL_A = 1` and that follows a logic. Create `REPLICATE_UPDATED_DATA` **before** `INC_COL_A` and your triggers will work as expected.

Checking that actual row values match the old row values would be a solution here, but maybe not what you need in your real app.

```
CREATE TRIGGER REPLICATE_UPDATED_DATA
AFTER UPDATE ON SAMPLE
REFERENCING NEW AS newrow OLD AS oldrow
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
UPDATE SAMPLE_CLONE SET COL_A = newrow.COL_A, COL_B = newrow.COL_B
  WHERE ID = newrow.ID
        and (col_a, col_b) = (old_row.col_a, old_row.col_b);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not the correct way to have a update (or insert) trigger change the value being written...  You want to make use of a `BEFORE` update(insert) trigger

```
-- Increment COL_A on every update
CREATE TRIGGER INC_COL_A BEFORE UPDATE ON SAMPLE
REFERENCING  OLD AS oldrow  NEW AS newrow  
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL 
WHEN (oldrow.COL_A = newrow.COL_A)
 SET newrow.COL_A = oldrow.COL_A+1 ;
```

Comment: That's a good approach, however, let's say I can't change the way `INC_COL_A` was defined (I oversimplified my scenario because there are more complex business triggers that I can't touch). 
Knowing that, is still possible to make the REPLICATE triggers work without changing the logic of the previous triggers?